# in a Group if records are present more than 1 with blank. delete from output

Tags: sql, sql-server

In a group of MFRNO,MFRNAME,MFRADDRESS AND ZIPCODE
IF there is two phone number and out of two if one is empty (''), then remove from result.
but if in a group there is only 1 record and phone number is blank then it should be retain in the output.

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE
(
MFRNO VARCHAR(50),  
MFRNAME  VARCHAR(50),
MFRADDRESS  VARCHAR(50),
ZIPCODE  VARCHAR(50),
FIRSTPHONE  VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT @TABLE


SELECT '10008886',  'TIPMASTER LTD',        'RIGG APPROACH',        'E107ON',''  UNION ALL
SELECT '10008886',  'TIPMASTER LTD',        'RIGG APPROACH',        'E107ON',   '02085390611'UNION ALL
SELECT '10012227',  'CAR BODY',        'UNSHINAGH LANE',        'BT623RL',  ''   UNION ALL
SELECT '40045002',  'MANCHESTER',          'GROVE PARK',        'WA168QE',  ''   UNION ALL
SELECT '40045002',  'MANCHESTER',          'GROVE PARK',        'WA168QE',  '07967967404'

MFRNO   MFRNAME MFRADDRESS  ZIPCODE FIRSTPHONE
10008886    TIPMASTER LTD   RIGG APPROACH   E107ON  02085390611
10012227    CAR BODY    UNSHINAGH LANE  BT623RL 
40045002    MANCHESTER  GROVE PARK  WA168QE 07967967404
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Max should do it:

```
select MFRNO, MFRNAME, MFRADDRESS, ZIPCODE, MAX(FIRSTPHONE)
from @TABLE
group by MFRNO, MFRNAME, MFRADDRESS, ZIPCODE
```